# property dispatch does not exist on type 'Observable<any>' issue when using redux in angular 6

Tags: angular6, angular-redux

I am trying to do simple redux application with angular 6.

**reducers.ts**

```
import { login,logout } from '../actions/actions';
export interface appReducer {
    login:boolean,
    user:String
}
const initialstate:appReducer={
    login:false,
    user:'guest'
}
export function reducer(state=initialstate,action):appReducer {
    switch(action.type) {
        case login:
            return {...state,login:true,user:action.payload}
        case logout:
            return {...state,login:false,user:action.payload}   
    }
    return state;
}
```

**actions.ts**

```
export const login="LOGIN";
export const logout="LOGOUT"
```

**index.ts**

```
import { reducer,appReducer } from './reducer';
import { ActionReducerMap }  from '@ngrx/store';
interface appState {
    appReducer:appReducer;
}
export const reducers:ActionReducerMap<appState>= {
    appReducer:reducer
}
```

**records.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient,HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Store }  from '@ngrx/store';
export class RecordsService {
  getLogin:boolean=false;
  constructor(private http:HttpClient,private store:Store<any>) { 
    this.recordFunc();
  }
     getState() {
        return this.store.select('appReducer');
      }
      updateState(action) {
        if(action.login==true) {
            return this.store.select('appReducer').dispatch({
                type:'LOGIN',
                payload:action.uname
            })
        }
        else {
            return this.store.select('appReducer').dispatch({
                type:'LOGOUT',
                payload:action.uname
            })
        }   
      }
}
```

in the above code I created reducers and successfully registered within the store module.Then I import the store in my service(records.service.ts) file.By subscribing into my getState() I get my current state but when I calling the updateState() to dispatch an action for updating the state it shows following error in my terminal and also update my state.

```
ERROR in src/app/records.service.ts(69,44): error TS2339: Property 'dispatch' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'.
src/app/records.service.ts(75,42): error TS2339: Property 'dispatch' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'.
```

Answer (score 3):

I face the same issue and found a quick fix.

Instead of using `store.select('appReducer').dispatch` just use `store.dispatch`.

Comment: Use like this this.store.dispatch({
                type:'LOGOUT',
                payload:action.uname
            })